# ionic emulate android not working

Tags: android, adt, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a blank project using ionic framework. But I'm getting the following error when I run the **ionic emulate android** command.

```
Error executing "adb devices": /bin/sh: 1: adb: not found
Error: /home/username/todo/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I also have added android sdk path to .bashrc file.

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/username/android/eclipse/adt-bundle/sdk/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$HOME/username/eclipse/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH"
```

I have also install the eclipse adt bundle for 64 bits. any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: See the error. Cordova asks `adb` and didn't find it. Add `adb` location path to globals

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. see the edited question. Is there anything wrong with setting the path.

Comment: If you type adb at the prompt, does it work? Forget cordova/ionic, just try adb.

Answer (score 1):

**Error executing "adb devices": /bin/sh: 1: adb: not found**

Do you have adb in your path? If not, put it. It comes with android sdk

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.I have added the android sdk path to bashrc file. see the edited question.

Comment: @Charith restart and then in terminal : abd --version. Does it work?

Comment: I check the version. but since it says adb han not installed, I install adb with sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb, command. But now I'm getting another error.  Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets .  then I delete the directory and start a new todo project. but now I even can not add android platform to the project. it gives the above error. please advice. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Charith you should install adb through path and not apt get. What went erong in that? Could you run adb version after a restart?

Comment: When I type adb, terminal displays to install adb, using apt get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59915/discussion-between-charith-and-eugene).